# Undefined method ::validate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

working in recover the password, and everything was working ok since i added a validator, but i get a error: "Undefined method ...\Password\PasswordController::validate"

The function im calling is postEmail

What am i doing wrong?

My code:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

trait ResetsPasswords
{

    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);


        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });


        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return redirect()
                       ->back()
                       ->with('status', trans($response));

            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return redirect()
                       ->back()
                       ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet is a bit messed up at the top so I can't see; does this Controller extend the base controller `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`? that should have a `ValidatesRequests` trait.

Answer (score 3):

A controller doesn't have a validate method unless you use the appropriate traits. You cannot use `validate()` function on `$this`. It will be working only if you have the `ValidatesRequests` trait is used on the controller

so just after

```
class PasswordController{
```

you have to insert the below

```
use ValidateRequests;
```

Comment: ello, thanks for answering, i just added the use ValidateRequests, that added, but than gave me this error: Trait '...\Api\Controllers\Password\ValidateRequests' not found"

Comment: put this at the top `use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;`